# Is this graph bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory

A planar depiction of a loop-free connected graph has 7 regions, each is a
polygon. The numbers of edges on the boundaries of the regions are respectively
3,3,3,3,3,4,5. **(a) Find the number of vertices of the graph.
(b) Is G bipartite?**

I figured out that part a) is 7 vertices.
So now we have

|V| = 7 |F| = 7 and |E| = 12

so for part b) I began trying to draw sample graphs and my initial intuition is that it isn't but how do I go ahead and properly prove that?

Comment: Are you acquainted with the theorem that [a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd-length cycles](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~kindred/cuc-only/math104/lectures/lect03.pdf)?

Comment: Yes, I was just reading into that. But didn't really understand it fully. I will read the link you have provided.

Comment: Still need help on this

Comment: @DevAllanPer: Math.SE gets a lot of traffic, so, very unfortunately, not every question gets the attention one might like ... or as quickly as one might like. "Bumping" a question with a "still need help" edit is not the appropriate way to bring more attention to it.

Comment: There is a region bounded by three edges.  Can you two-color its vertices?

Comment: A graph is bipartite if and only if you can properly color its vertices in 2 colors. But vertices of a triangle can't be colored in three colors so this graph is not bipartite.

Comment: did you mean two when you said "can't be colored in *three* colors so this graph is not bipartite"?

Comment: can't be color in two colors sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, the graph on part a) could look like this:[image]